# Next steps for students' project

Tags: game-industry, playtesting, prototyping

I teach a basic course on game development, in which students design a game idea and write a digital prototype in Unity - about 5 minutes demonstrating the main idea and gameplay. Some of the teams did really great jobs and I would like to encourage them to continue developing their game beyond the course, but I am not sure what the next steps should be. In particular:

- Where can they get more professional review on their prototype? There are websites that review games, but usually they are looking for complete games, not just prototypes.
- Where can they get playtesters that will help them improve their prototype and make it a full game? Currently their game is in itch.io, but it is hard to draw attention to it.

Comment: Have you considered social media? Twitter and Discord are great ways to connect with gamedev communities informally.

Comment: I also want to add that reddit has some decent subreddits on games. There are communities such as r/unity3D and r/gamedev, where your can post about your game, and r/playmygame where you can show your complete game.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed there are many places to go to. Do you know of a resource (e.g. a book or online course) that teaches useful strategies for this game-prototype marketing?

Comment: Bring a laptop to starbucks and offer cappuccino to anyone who tests a mechanic. It really does work.